# How to fix error when adding array functions after main?

Tags: arrays, int, constants, void, fill

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void FillArray (int x[50], const int Size);
void PrintArray (int x[50], const int Size);

int main()
{
    const int SizeArray = 10;
    int A[SizeArray] = {0};
    FillArray (A, SizeArray);
    PrintArray (A, SizeArray);

    return 0;
}

void FillArray (int x[50], const int Size)
{
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Please enter an integer: ";
        cin >> x[i];
    }
}

void PrintArray (int x[50], const int Size)
{
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
    cout << endl << x[i];
}
}
```

The error I get is below. I have to create new functions that can read and print arrays respectively. The above is my main function followed by the read (fill) array. It won't run though.

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Some, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  Some.cpp
>   1>Some.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl PrintArray(int * const,int)" (?PrintArray@@YAXQAHH@Z) referenced in function _main
>   1>C:\Users\GmxTrey\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Some\Debug\Some.exe : fatal error >LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Sorry, just added it. It runs correctly now, but it simply repeats "Please enter an integer: " now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `FillArray` is declared and defined, but `PrintArray` is only declared, but not defined; this is why the linker complains. You need to provide a definition of `PrintArray` to address this problem.

Comment: Sorry, just added it. It runs correctly now, but it simply repeats "Please enter an integer: " now. Nothing else happens.

Comment: @GmxTrey Do you enter ten integers one by one, following each one by an `[Enter]`?

Comment: After I enter all ten numbers, it simply reads them back to me in the order I put them in then I pause the system.

Comment: But that's precisely what your program is telling the computer to do: prompt the users for ten integer numbers, store them into an array, and print them back! Your program works precisely as coded.

Comment: Sorry, first time doing this and the way my professor explained it, it was supposed to do a bunch of other stuff. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it.